# What alternative is there to the insanely expensive Enum.IsDefined() in C# 4.0?

Tags: c#-4.0, enums

I need to perform this operation many times on my data:

```
public void AddBehavior(BehaviorTypes type)
{
    if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(BehaviorTypes), type))
    {
    switch (type)
    {
        case BehaviorTypes.render:
            return new renderable();
        break;   
    }
}
```

That is two explicit function calls and an object boxing/unboxing operation! This operation is too expensive just to bounds check an enum. Does anyone know a cheaper alternative?

Comment: `BehaviorTypes` is an enum, right ? If so, you probably mean `typeof(BehaviorTypes)` ?

Comment: And btw, the implementation of IsDefined cost a lot more than the two calls and the boxing in your code ;) It's designed to support string or int representing an enum value, so it does quite a lot of works !

Comment: Yes that is what I meant. I actually tried to get rid of that and just use BehaviorTypes as the type, but no.

Comment: You may use `type.GetType()` instead, if you wish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pretty standard trick is to add members to the enum declaration that specify the first and last value:

```
enum BehaviorTypes {
    First = One,    
    One = 1,
    Two,
    Three,
    Last = Three
}
```

Now it is a superfast test, takes about a nanosecond:

```
public void AddBehavior(BehaviorTypes type)
{
    if (type >= BehaviorTypes.First && type <= BehaviorTypes.Last) {
       // etc..
    }
}
```

Do note that your switch statement already eliminates the need for this check.

Comment: Two enums can have the same value ? I've learned something today, thanks ^^ Definitly a good solution, if you have the hand on the enum, and if there is no gap between the integers of the enum.

Comment: Yeah, I can catch it in the `default` in this case and eliminate the check altogether. I was going to write that and select it as the correct answer(as that is what I am doing in the program I am writing). however your answer is definitely more generally useful. It is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you both.

Comment: What if you have enum { a=1, c=3 } and you submit 2 ?

Comment: Then you chose your enum values poorly.  A switch would be required.

Answer (score 1):

You could extract all existing values of your enum type with Enum.GetValues in an optimized collection, in a static member, once and for all. And you'll just have to search that collection next.

I'ld guess the fastest, if only one enum is in consideration, would be an array of booleans, telling you if your integral exists in the enum. Except the construction of this array (cost once), you'll have a convertion of an enum to int, and a read access in an array (which is the fastest you can get if I'm not mistaken ?).

Comment: GetValues on an array is O(1), so it's pretty fast ^^ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2zexc3z9.aspx

Comment: You may want to check with GetUpperBound btw.

Answer (score 1):

A little known fact about .NET is that you can declare extension methods on enums. Avoiding boxing would be a good reason to do so. For easy maintenance, you can define the static method in the same file as your enum so you know to change them at the same time.

```cs
public enum BehaviorTypes
{
    Render,
    Foo,
    Bar
}

public static class BehaviorTypesExtensions
{
    public static bool IsDefined(this BehaviorTypes behaviorTypes)
    {
        return behaviorTypes >= BehaviorTypes.Render && behaviorTypes <= BehaviorTypes.Bar;
    }
}
```

### Usage

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (BehaviorTypes value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(BehaviorTypes)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{value} is defined: {value.IsDefined()}");
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"43 is defined: {((BehaviorTypes)43).IsDefined()}");

        // Render is defined: True
        // Foo is defined: True
        // Bar is defined: True
        // 43 is defined: False
    }
}
```